# "he likes but I don't" or "he likes but I"

Tags: american-english

What is most used?
Means the same?

A) He likes but I don't.
B) He likes but I.

Comment: Neither one is correct. _Like_ requires a direct object. If there is one, A is correct: _He likes raspberries but I don't_. However, B is incorrect; conjunction reduction does not delete the verb in a second clause if it's not the same as the verb in the first clause. Since this is negative, it's not the same and must be retained. Furthermore, _but_ means _and_ -- it does not indicate negation by itself, merely surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't like the same thing he does, then A is partially correct. You still need an object, though.

You cannot just say 'He likes but I don't.' At the very least you need a pronoun referring to what it is he likes that you son't.

"He likes this but I don't."

Comment: In casual conversation the object can sometimes be omitted.  "Each of you can have a cookie if you like." "I like! I like!" or "If you would like, you and Billy can each have a cookie. In fact Billy, you can have two."  "He likes, but I don't."

Comment: At a push you /can/ say "He likes, but I don't like cheese". But this is just a contraction of "He likes cheese, but I don't like cheese". As the others say, likes needs an object, even if it's just "it". But it would be better to say "He likes cheese, but I don't".